# Tree with checkBox

Tags: android, checkbox, treeview

Good day!
It was necessary to create a list-tree, approximately, as represented in the picture:

https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/08/01/article-about-checkboxes-in-a-wpf-treeview/

Forgive me for this, the site itself does not allow me to insert the picture

The tree consists of a check of the boxes, when you click on the parent, the checkboxes are displayed / removed from the child elements. In addition to the checkboxes, each element of the tree has its own parameter (byte array).

Actually, it is necessary to read the state of the checkboxes after pressing the checkboxes (by clicking, say, a button), and taking the values ​​(the same array of bytes), the name, the name of the tab and writing it to another array / list, etc.

The main question is how to create a TreeView where the state of the child elements depends on the parent and how to assign them, among other things, also the values.

I saw many examples, but I did not find it. Just come across the broken links.

I could implement only the checkbox list on my own, but the child elements do not react to changing the state of the parent.

The code is shown below.

ExpandableListAdapter.java

```
    public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listHeaderData, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData){
        this.context = context;
        this.listDataHeader = listHeaderData;
        this.listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
        }
        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

child_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="308dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="asd"
        android:textSize="20dip" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/lblListChildCheckbox"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textSize="17dp" />



</LinearLayout>
```

group_row.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
            android:layout_width="306dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/lblListHeaderCheckbox"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="17dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

listings.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:andoid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        andoid:layout_width="match_parent"
        andoid:layout_height="match_parent"
        andoid:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            andoid:id="@+id/add_template"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            andoid:layout_width="match_parent"
            andoid:layout_height="wrap_content"
            andoid:layout_gravity="center"
            andoid:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            andoid:text="Добавить шаблон" />

        <ExpandableListView
            andoid:id="@+id/listing"
            andoid:layout_width="match_parent"
            andoid:layout_height="wrap_content"></ExpandableListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Choise_list.java

```
public class Choise_List extends Activity {

    private Button add_template;

    class Lists{
        String page;
        String name;
        String type;
        byte[] val;
    }

    Context context;

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    List<String> pages;

    ArrayList< Map<String, String> > childDataItem = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Lists> structure_list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void createListsList(ArrayList<byte[]> ch_check) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        for (int i = 0; i < ch_check.size(); i++){
            if(Arrays.equals( ch_check.get(i), "PAGE".getBytes( Charset.forName("UTF-8") ) ) ){
                Lists lists = new Lists();
                int state = i;
                lists.page = new String( ch_check.get(++state), "UTF-8" );
                lists.name = new String( ch_check.get(++state), "UTF-8" );
                lists.type = new String( ch_check.get(++state), "UTF-8" );
                lists.val = ch_check.get(++state);

                i = state;
                structure_list.add(lists);
            }
        }
    }

    private void prepareListData(){

        HashSet<String> used = new HashSet<>();

        int count = 0;

        pages = new ArrayList<>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        for(int i = 0; i < structure_list.size(); i++){
            if(used.contains(structure_list.get(i).page)){
                continue;
            } else {
                used.add(structure_list.get(i).page);
            }

            String new_page_name = "";
            ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();

            positions.add(i);
            for(int j = i + 1; j < structure_list.size(); j++){

                if(structure_list.get(i).page.equals(structure_list.get(j).page)){
                    positions.add(j);
                }
            }

            childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

            List<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(Integer p : positions){
                new_page_name = structure_list.get(p).page;
                child.add(structure_list.get(p).name);
            }
            pages.add(new_page_name);
            listDataChild.put(pages.get(count), child);
            count++;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listings);


        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listing);

        ArrayList<byte[]> ch_check = new ArrayList<>();

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            MyObject myObj = (MyObject) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(MyObject.class.getCanonicalName());

            if(myObj == null){
                ch_check = null;
            } else{
                ch_check = myObj.choise;
            }
        }

        if(ch_check != null){

            try {
                createListsList(ch_check);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            prepareListData();

            expListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, pages, listDataChild);
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

                    return false;
                }
            });

            expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), pages.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pages.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),pages.get(groupPosition) + " : " + listDataChild.get(pages.get(groupPosition)).get( childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.lblListChildCheckbox);
                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
                    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            checkBox.setChecked(isChecked);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample :-)

MainActiivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button clearChecks;
ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
ExpandableListViewAdapter mExpandableListAdapter;
int mLastExpandedPosition = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandedListView);
    clearChecks = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClearChecks);

    List<String> listTitle = genGroupList();
    mExpandableListAdapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(this, listTitle, genChildList(listTitle));
    mExpandableListView.setAdapter(mExpandableListAdapter);

    mExpandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if(mLastExpandedPosition != -1 && (mLastExpandedPosition != groupPosition)){
                mExpandableListView.collapseGroup(mLastExpandedPosition);
            }
            mLastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
        }
    });

    clearChecks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mExpandableListAdapter.clearChecks();
        }
    });
}

private List<String> genGroupList(){
    List<String> listGroup = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
        listGroup.add("Group: " + i);
    }
    return listGroup;
}

private Map<String, List<ChildItemSample>> genChildList(List<String> header){
    Map<String, List<ChildItemSample>> listChild = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0; i<header.size(); i++){
        List<ChildItemSample> testDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        int a = (int)(Math.random() * 8);
        for(int j=0; j<a; j++){
            ChildItemSample testItem = new ChildItemSample("Child " + (j + 1));
            testDataList.add(testItem);
        }
        listChild.put(header.get(i), testDataList);
    }
    return  listChild;
}

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClearChecks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear Checks" />
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandedListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ExpandableListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

ChildItemSample.java:

```
public class ChildItemSample {
private boolean checked;
private String name;
public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
}
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public ChildItemSample(){
    checked = false;
    name = "";
}
public ChildItemSample(String name){
    checked = false;
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

ExpandableListViewAdapter.java:

```
public class ExpandableListViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<String> listGroup;
private Map<String, List<ChildItemSample>> listChild;
private int checkedBoxesCount;
private boolean[] checkedGroup;

public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> listGroup, Map<String,
        List<ChildItemSample>> listChild) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listGroup = listGroup;
    this.listChild = listChild;
    checkedBoxesCount = 0;
    checkedGroup = new boolean[listGroup.size()];
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return listGroup.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return listChild.get(listGroup.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public String getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return listGroup.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public ChildItemSample getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return listChild.get(listGroup.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    String itemGroup = getGroup(groupPosition);
    GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expanded_list_group, null);
        groupViewHolder = new GroupViewHolder();
        groupViewHolder.tvGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_group);
        groupViewHolder.cbGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.cb_group);
        groupViewHolder.cbGroup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int pos = (int)view.getTag();
                checkedGroup[pos] = !checkedGroup[pos];
                for(ChildItemSample item : listChild.get(listGroup.get(pos))){
                    item.setChecked(checkedGroup[pos]);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        view.setTag(groupViewHolder);
    }else {
        groupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }
    groupViewHolder.tvGroup.setText(String.format("%s (%d)", itemGroup, getChildrenCount(groupPosition)));
    groupViewHolder.cbGroup.setChecked(checkedGroup[groupPosition]);
    groupViewHolder.cbGroup.setTag(groupPosition);
    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ChildItemSample expandedListText = getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
    ChildViewHolder childViewHolder;
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expanded_list_item, null);
        childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();
        childViewHolder.tvChild = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_child);
        childViewHolder.cbChild = view.findViewById(R.id.cb_child);
        childViewHolder.cbChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;
                ChildItemSample selectedItem = listChild.get(listGroup.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
                selectedItem.setChecked(cb.isChecked());
                if(cb.isChecked()){
                    checkedBoxesCount++;
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Checked value is: " +
                                    listChild.get(listGroup.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    checkedBoxesCount--;
                    if(checkedBoxesCount == 0){
                        Toast.makeText(context,"nothing checked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(context,"unchecked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        view.setTag(childViewHolder);
    }else {
        childViewHolder = (ChildViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }
    childViewHolder.cbChild.setChecked(expandedListText.isChecked());
    childViewHolder.tvChild.setText(expandedListText.getName());
    return view;
}

public void clearChecks() {
    for(int i=0; i<checkedGroup.length; i++) checkedGroup[i] = false;
    for(List<ChildItemSample> value : listChild.values()) {
        for (ChildItemSample sample : value) {
            sample.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
    checkedBoxesCount = 0;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

private class GroupViewHolder {
    CheckBox cbGroup;
    TextView tvGroup;
}

private class ChildViewHolder {
    CheckBox cbChild;
    TextView tvChild;
}
}
```

expanded_list_group.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

expanded_list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb_child"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_child"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Note: The checked state of child is stored inside child class while group's checked state is stored in an array inside adapter. Hope that helps!