# SQLite grouped items and expandable list views for android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, expandablelistview

so I'm stuck on something probably pretty basic. I've got data stored in an SQLite database table and want to display that in an expandable list view. The data basically forms as headings and subheadings. There's many sub-headings to a single heading.

Retrieving the data is pretty straightforward. The part I'm stuck at is taking that data and giving it to the expandable list view.

I want the expandable list view to display the headings as the item that can be expanded, with the subheadings as the child items. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

You must provide an adapter to ExpandableListView. There is a base class [adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter) that you can extend it for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

For creating the data lists. Assume Column1 is Heading, Column2 is SubHeading, try this in activity/fragment:

```
    ArrayList<String> headings = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> subheadings = new HashMap<>();
    String heading, subheading;
    do{
        heading = cursor.getString(1);
        subheading = cursor.getString(2);
        ArrayList<String> tmpChild;
        if(headings.contains(heading)){
            tmpChild = subheadings.get(heading);
        }else{
            headings.add(heading);
            tmpChild = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        tmpChild.add(subheading);
        subheadings.put(heading, tmpChild);
    }while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

For the adapter, try my answer here: [Tree with checkBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49622120/tree-with-checkbox/49765749#49765749)

Hope that helps!